# Recreating a large complex query with left outer joins in LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, t-sql, entity-framework-6

I'm looking for some advice to tackle this problem. We have this large SQL query with many left outer joins.

Here is the query:

```
Select Top 1 WA.BHATUS_ID, WA.[CRMBHG_WORKINGACCOUNT_ID], BA.BHATUS_ID, BA.[CRMBHG_BILLINGACCOUNT_ID], BAD.BHATUS_ID, [BAD].[CRMBHG_BILLINGADDRESS_ID], SAD.BHATUS_ID, [SAD].[CRMBHG_SERVICEADDRESS_ID], C.BHATUS_ID, [C].[CRMBHG_CONTACT_ID]
From BillingHiBHory As BH With (NoLock)
    Left Outer Join WorkingAccount As WA With (NoLock)
        On WA.UniversalAccountId = BH.UniversalAccountId
            And WA.BillingRegion = BH.BillingRegion
    Left Outer Join BillingAccount As BA With (NoLock)
        On BA.UniversalAccountId = BH.UniversalAccountId
            And BA.BillingRegion = BH.BillingRegion
    Left Outer Join BillingAddress As BAD With (NoLock)
        On BAD.Grouping = BH.Grouping
            And BAD.SubGrouping = BH.SubGrouping
            And BAD.BillingRegion = BH.BillingRegion
    Left Outer Join dbo.SubScriberInfo SUB With (NoLock)
            On SUB.Grouping = BH.Grouping
            And SUB.SubGrouping = BH.SubGrouping
            And SUB.BillingRegion = BH.BillingRegion
    Left Outer Join ServiceAddress As SAD With (NoLock)
        On SAD.ControlNumberAssigned = SUB.ServceControlNum
            And SAD.BillingRegion = SUB.BillingRegion
    Left Outer Join Contact As C With (NoLock)
        On BH.AccountNum = C.AccountNum
            And BH.BillingRegion = C.BillingRegion
Where BH.Grouping = @Grouping
    And BH.SubGrouping = @SubGrouping
Order By BH.SequenceOrder, WA.StatusDate Desc, BA.StatusDate Desc, BAD.StatusDate Desc, SAD.StatusDate Desc, C.StatusDate Desc
```

Here's my first crack at the LINQ syntax...

```
var statusIds = (
    from wa in db.WorkingAccount
    from ba in db.BillingAccount
    from bad in db.BillingAddress
    from si in db.SubscriberInfo
    from sad in db.ServiceAddress
    from c in db.CRMSTG_CONTACT
    where wa.UniversalAccountId == UniversalSubscriberId && wa.BillingRegion == BillingRegion
    where ba.UniversalAccountId == UniversalSubscriberId && ba.BillingRegion == BillingRegion
    where bad.Grouping == Grouping && bad.SubGrouping == SubGrouping && bad.BillingRegion == BillingRegion
    where si.Grouping == Grouping && si.SubGrouping == SubGrouping && si.BillingRegion == BillingRegion
    where sad.ControlNumberAssigned  == si.ServceControlNum && sad.BillingRegion == BillingRegion
    where c.AccountNum == AccountNumber && c.BillingRegion == BillingRegion
    orderby wa.StatusDate descending, ba.StatusDate descending, bad.StatusDate descending, sad.StatusDate descending, c.StatusDate descending
    select new
    {
        workingAddressStatusId = wa.StatusId,
        billingAccountStatusId = ba.StatusId,
        billingAddressStatusId = bad.StatusId,
        serviceAddressStatusId = sad.StatusId,
        contactStatusId = c.StatusDate
    }
    ).FirstOrDefault();
```

This mostly works but feels like a big hack. Where this falls down is when one of the StatusId values comes back as null and statusIds ends up being null as well.

I'm sure there's a better way to do this. I'm open to suggestions.

As a note, yes, I'm aware of the risks associated with "With (NoLock)" option on the TSQL, we're a secondary app on a very busy database and we don't want to create blocking chains as billing and support staff do their work. For what we're doing, the NoLock is a non-issue. It's not like we're doing multiple unions of queries with aggregators. ;)

Comment: hi, good day, if possible, can you include the domain structure of each?

Comment: Oh, it's an inconsistent mishmash of data types coming out of an AS400 database into staging MSSQL database before it gets cleaned up and moves into the MSSQL database. Let me write up the essentials of the keys we're linking on.

Comment: in my opinion, if this is part refactoring a legacy database, I would save this query in a stored procedure, and have EF call the sp, rather than trying to finagle linq to generate this particular sql for you. I would then address the multiple left joins by adjusting the data model to no longer need so many.

Comment: Unfortunately, we're not refactoring the legacy database. The AS400 is a big and active data component that manages some core business processes so that's not changing anytime soon. There is part of me that's saying I should've just run it as batch SQL under an ADO.Net recordset and call it good, but know, I wanted to figure this out in LINQ. I could've begged for the permission to get a stored proc added to the production server and import the function, but see the above interest. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's true that you have a lot of left outer joins, and also that left outer joins are not naturally supported in LINQ, but the pattern is well known - take a look at **Left Outer Join** and **Composite Keys** sections in [join clause (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx), so all you need is to follow the pattern:

```
from bh in db.BillingHiBHory

join wa in db.WorkingAccount
on new { bh.UniversalAccountId, bh.BillingRegion }
equals new { wa.UniversalAccountId, wa.BillingRegion }
into bh_wa from wa in bh_wa.DefaultIfEmpty() // this turns the above (inner) join into left outer join

join ba in db.BillingAccount
on new { bh.UniversalAccountId, bh.BillingRegion }
equals new { ba.UniversalAccountId, ba.BillingRegion }
into bh_ba from ba in bh_ba.DefaultIfEmpty()

join bad in db.BillingAddress
on new { bh.Grouping, bh.SubGrouping, bh.BillingRegion }
equals new { bad.Grouping, bad.SubGrouping, bad.BillingRegion }
into bh_bad from bad in bh_bad.DefaultIfEmpty()

join si in db.SubscriberInfo
on new { bh.Grouping, bh.SubGrouping, bh.BillingRegion }
equals new { si.Grouping, si.SubGrouping, si.BillingRegion }
into bh_si from si in bh_si.DefaultIfEmpty()

join sad in db.ServiceAddress
on new { si.ServceControlNum, si.BillingRegion }
equals new { sad.ControlNumberAssigned, sad.BillingRegion }
into si_sad from sad in si_sad.DefaultIfEmpty()

join c in db.CRMSTG_CONTACT
on new { bh.AccountNum, bh.BillingRegion }
equals new { c.AccountNum, c.BillingRegion }
into bh_c from c in bh_c.DefaultIfEmpty()

where bh.Grouping == Grouping
   && bh.SubGrouping == SubGrouping

// ... (the rest)
```

One detail to consider is to include nullable cast when selecting non nullable fields from the `right` part of the left outer join. For instance, if the `StatusId` type is `int`, then you need to use something like this:

```
select new 
{
    workingAddressStatusId = (int?)wa.StatusId,
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Your code sample has bug in the anonymous types; they should include the member name. I have a problem with a timeout that's coming back really fast but this answer solves this problem. `new { grouping = bh.Grouping,  subGrouping = bh.SubGrouping, ...`

Comment: Also, using anonymous types to perform and equals operations is really slick. I hadn't thought of that. Though I did learn that your member names must be the same or you'll get compile time errors.

Comment: Actually the names of the fields of anonymous types are not required to be provided explicitly and are inferred most of the time. I've just forgot to name explicitly one of the  `si_sad` join fields that have different names, because yes - two anonymous types are considered one and the same if both name and type of the fields match.

Comment: Let me be a little more clear. `... on new { value1 = db1.value1, value2 = db2.value2} equals new { value1 = db2.value1, value2 = db2.value2}` will compile while `... on new { value1 = db1.value1, value2 = db2.value2} equals new { valueA = db2.value1, valueB = db2.value2}` won't compile.